# Reading a process' memory

Tags: c, winapi, memory, windows-10

So i have this function iv'e written in C, it's supposed to scan a process' memory. I'm running it on notepad, but since it's failing iv'e tried a few more processes. It never works properly and the output is always as follows :

```
0x00010000
0x7FFE0000
0x7FFE1000
```

When i'm using windows 7 the function works just fine. Here it is :

```
int ScanProcess(int pid)
{
    HANDLE hProc;
    SYSTEM_INFO si;
    MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION mbi;
    LPVOID *minAddress, *maxAddress;

    GetSystemInfo(&si);
    minAddress = si.lpMinimumApplicationAddress;
    maxAddress = si.lpMaximumApplicationAddress;

    hProc = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, NULL, pid);

    if (!hProc) {
        printf("[-] OpenProcess() failed.\n");
        return 0;}

    while (minAddress < maxAddress)
    {
        printf("0x%08X\n", minAddress);
        if(!VirtualQueryEx(hProc, minAddress, &mbi, sizeof(mbi))) printf("[-] VirtualQueryEx() failed. %d\n", GetLastError());
        if (mbi.State == MEM_COMMIT && mbi.Protect == PAGE_READWRITE)
        {
            printf("MEM_COMMIT\n"); //When the scan would work i will read the memory and work with it.
        }
        minAddress = (LPVOID)((long)mbi.BaseAddress + mbi.RegionSize);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Can someone figure out the problem? thanks :)

@Harry Johnston, this is what i got so far.

```
int ScanProcess(int pid)
{
HANDLE hProc;
SYSTEM_INFO si;
MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION mbi;
DWORD64 minAddress, maxAddress;

GetSystemInfo(&si);
minAddress = (DWORD64)si.lpMinimumApplicationAddress;
maxAddress = (DWORD64)si.lpMaximumApplicationAddress;

hProc = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, NULL, pid);

if (!hProc) {
    printf("[-] OpenProcess() failed.\n");
    return 0;}

while (minAddress < maxAddress)
{
    printf("0x%08X\n", minAddress);
    if(!VirtualQueryEx(hProc, (LPCVOID)minAddress, &mbi, sizeof(mbi))) printf("[-] VirtualQueryEx() failed. %d\n", GetLastError());
    if (mbi.State == MEM_COMMIT && mbi.Protect == PAGE_READWRITE)
    {
        printf("MEM_COMMIT\n"); //When the scan would work i will read the memory and work with it.
    }
    minAddress = (DWORD64)mbi.BaseAddress + mbi.RegionSize;
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't know if it's related, but you have one too many levels of indirection. `minAddress` and `maxAddress` should be `LPVOID`, not `LPVOID*`,

Comment: that's right. anyway, i changed them to just LPVOID and the output remained same.

Comment: Can you be more specific what you mean by "never works properly"? Step through the code in a debugger and clarify which step does not do what you expect.

Comment: VirtualQueryEx returns the addresses for every process, and there's never a memory block i can work with. the if statement that checks. mbi.State and mbi.Protect is never true. on windows 7 the code behaves completely different

Comment: what do you mean by: "the code behaves completely different"?

Comment: the function calls and data types are all 'windows' OS so it will not work under other OSs.  So what do you mean by: "iv'e tried a few more processes"?  do you mean other OSs?  do you mean other processes on the current computer?  Do you mean other versions of windows besides windows 7?

Comment: regarding the line that calls `VirtualQueryEx()` when the call fails, the code, besides printing an error message needs to exit().  Otherwise, the following lines of code are trying to use the `mbi`, which is not set to any valid value(s)

Comment: there are three requirements, listed at: <https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366786%28v=vs.85%29.aspx>  1)  Minimum supported client: Windows XP [desktop apps only] 2) Minimum supported server Windows Server 2003 [desktop apps only] 3) Header: WinNT.h (include Windows.h)   Does your code/environment support these three requirements?

Comment: the `VirtualQueryEx()` function does NOT return every process.  it only returns the page usage for the process identified by the first parameter.

Comment: suggest checking for the other `.state` values and the other `protect` values so you can determine exactly what your looking at.  two switch() statements should be enough to implement that.

Comment: i know that WINAPI's are not supposed to be windows version dependent. when i ran this code in windows 7 it worked perfect. and by trying it with a few processes i meant i tried reading different processes' memory, all in windows 10

Comment: i checked for another `.state` and `.protect` codes and the results where weird. but anyway, it's obvious that that's not the problem. the results being exactly the same with different processes and the results being so few indicate that something is not right.

Comment: when outputting the error message when `VirtualQueryEx()` fails, suggest using the windows function: `FormatMessage()` so the reason for the failure is also displayed.

Comment: "i know that WINAPI's are not supposed to be windows version dependent"  Not true.   And the page I referenced in an earlier comment verifies that your statement is not correct.

Comment: the thing is, VirtualQueryEx() does not fail. iv'e added the code output at the top of the page, in case VirtualQueryEx() failed it'd be printed out. can you try running the code so you see what's going on?

Comment: `long` is a 32-bit type, you need to use a 64-bit type.  And as you correctly guessed, you need to be a 64-bit process to query other 64-bit processes.  You'll probably also need to fix up the `printf` call so that it expects a 64-bit variable.

Comment: why do i need a 64-bit type? and now i'm realizing that i don't really understand the difference between long and int. can you explain that for me?

Comment: and another thing, i'd really appreciate a correct version of my code. it would be the best answer.

Comment: forgot to tag @HarryJohnston

Comment: Memory addresses are 64 bit, so to do arithmetic on them you must use a 64-bit type such as `long long`.  When you convert `mbi.baseAddress` to a `long` you truncate the address, leading to an infinite loop.  Re your other question: in Visual Studio, there is no difference between `int` and `long`.

Comment: @HarryJohnston this is still not working, what am i missing? i use `DWORD64` for `minAddress` and `maxAddress`. i seem to be missing something. can you please submit an answer with a valid code snippet?

Comment: Can you post what you've got so far?

Comment: @HarryJohnston i posted what iv'e got so far as an answer

Comment: What you've posted works perfectly for me (on Windows 7 x64) except that the `printf` needs to say `printf("0x%08I64X\n", minAddress);` ; what output are you getting?

Comment: Are you sure you're pointing it at a normal process and not, for example, a Windows Store process?

Comment: i'm trying it on notepad.exe, pretty basic i guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this version:

```
int ScanProcess(int pid)
{
    HANDLE hProc;
    SYSTEM_INFO si;
    MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION mbi;
    LPVOID minAddress, maxAddress;

    GetSystemInfo(&si);
    minAddress = si.lpMinimumApplicationAddress;
    maxAddress = si.lpMaximumApplicationAddress;

    hProc = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, NULL, pid);

    if (!hProc) {
        printf("[-] OpenProcess() failed.\n");
        return 0;}

    while (minAddress < maxAddress)
    {
        printf("0x%p\n", minAddress);
        if(!VirtualQueryEx(hProc, minAddress, &mbi, sizeof(mbi))) printf("[-] VirtualQueryEx() failed. %d\n", GetLastError());
        if (mbi.State == MEM_COMMIT && mbi.Protect == PAGE_READWRITE)
        {
            printf("MEM_COMMIT\n"); //When the scan would work i will read the memory and work with it.
        }
        minAddress = (LPBYTE)mbi.BaseAddress + mbi.RegionSize;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

It uses `LPVOID` as a pointer type is fine for this application, the only real change is the pointer arithmetic is done using a cast to `LPBYTE` (since you can't add void pointers).

The other change is to use `%p` as the `printf` formatting string, since this will work correctly with a 64-bit pointer.

Comment: It works! thanks a lot, i started getting frustrated. the `%p` is new to me and i understand its usage so thanks for that. can you explain me the logic of using `LPBYTE` and why it works?

Comment: @hyprnir `LPBYTE` is a byte-sized pointer, and since `mbi.RegionSize` is measured in bytes you need to use a compatible pointer size for the arithmetic to work.

Comment: i tried using `char*` and it wouldn't work. iv'e done some reading and found out that `LPBYTE` is `unsigned char*`. can you explain me the difference between `char*` and `unsigned char*` when working with pointers?

Comment: @hyprnir `char*` works as well (I just tried it). There's no difference in this case between the two - they're both byte-sized pointers. The only difference comes when dereferencing the pointer which you're not doing in this code.

Comment: what do you mean by dereferencing a pointer? you mind writing a little example?

Comment: That seems off-topic for your question. Pointers are a basic part of the language, if you don't know what dereferencing means you're probably jumping in too deep.

Comment: i was quick to ask again since i'm really happy with the help iv'e been getting. i figured i'd just look it up and turns out i do know what it is, i just didn't know it's called that way. so thanks everybody for your help :)